# How to insert entities with xml starlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I am trying to replace an attribute value with a text containing an ampersand.

```
<property value="My Product&#x0A;Developed by me">
```

What would be the correct syntax to replace a given attribute by the text above?

So far I tried

```
xmlStarlet\xml.exe edit --inplace --update "/.../property/@value" --value "My Product&#x0A;Developed by me" myXml.xml
```

but I end up by getting & replaced by &amp; which is not intended in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`xmlstarlet`**'s `unesc` command:

Sample `input.xml` file/fragment:

```
<root>
    <property value="empty"></property>
</root>
```

---

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//property/@value' -v 'My Product&#x0A;Developed by me' input.xml \
| xmlstarlet unesc
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <property value="My Product&#x0A;Developed by me"/>
</root>
```