# Cannot add ampersand (&) as value for attribute in xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I wrote a script to update `server.xml` with xmlstarlet (1.6.1).

I want to insert a subnode and add an attribute with a value that contains an ampersand (`&`) character.

Unfortunately xmlstrarlet is always changing `&` into `&amp;`

Do you have any idea how to force xmlstarlet to save `&` instead `&amp;`?

Example of my code:

```
xmlstarlet ed -P -L -s "/Server/Service" -t elem -n "Connector" -v "" \
--var Connector '$prev' \
-i "/Server/Service/Connector" -t attr -n "relaxedQueryChars" -v "[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;" \
server.xml
```

**Result**:

```
relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&amp;#x5c;&amp;#x60;&amp;quot;&amp;lt;&amp;gt;"
```

**Desired result**:

```
relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"
```

I tried escape all `&` characters but it was not helpful, instead I got `\&amp;`

**XML sample**:

```
<Server>
  <Service>
    <Connector attribute="value"/>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

**XML after xmlstarlet update**:

```
 <Server>
   <Service>
     <Connector relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;" attribute="value"/>
   </Service>
 </Server>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are missing a sample of the input XML file for helping you.

Comment: Try literal characters like `<>` instead of `&lt;&gt;`. Find some way in your shell to escape the double quote.

Comment: Hello guys, thank you for your help. Article [How to insert entities with xml starlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809555/how-to-insert-entities-with-xml-starlet) was helpfull and solve my problem with ampersand.